# Unzip wrongly: All files are scattered in the current directory

Tags: linux, directory, zip, unzip

On CentOS, I wanted to unzip files in `A.zip` into `./A/`. However, I didn't notice that there were hundreds of files in `A.zip` and I just use `unzip A.zip`. So now these extra files are all in the current directory. How could I solve this problem?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

unzip -Z1 is the zip info mode which basically returns the files which were zipped. The output is then piped onto other command which removes that file based on the input(from the previous command).

*Assuming, first you take a proper backup of that folder.*

```
unzip -Z1 t1.zip | xargs rm -f
```

> If the zip files has folders inside of it then

```
unzip -Z1 t1.zip | xargs rm -rf
```

t1.zip is the zip file which I tested with.

Comment: That's cooooool! Thank you very much, It really works. And in addition, if there is a folder in the zipped file, the command is ```unzip -Z1 t1.zip | xargs rm -rf```

Comment: Yes, you can work with options inside rm command. The fact that you told files in question, I just assumed that to be. I shall edit my answer.